# Android Market issue with manifest file

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

I have a problem while publishing on the Market. My application does not use autofocus feature but when I publish it on the market I see in console following:

```
android.hardware.camera
android.hardware.camera.autofocus
```

And here are permissions and features that I request in manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Can anyone tell me what's the problem please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the proper `<uses-feature>` tags included in your manifest? That means only

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

The doc states:

> For example, if an application requests the CAMERA permission but does not declare a  element for android.hardware.camera, Google Play considers that the application requires a camera and should not be shown to users whose devices do not offer a camera.

*from [filtering based on implicit features](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#implicit)*

You can check [this list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions) and see that the two features mentioned by you are assumed when you use the camera permission and don't state anything in your manifest. Add the above code snippet and it should get reduced to just the camera-feature.